# Replacing NA by preceding date + 7 Days

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

Actually, I have converted data something like this

```
code  name  returns  year  week
1     A     0.66     2000  01 
2     A     0.32     2000  02
3     A     0.66     2000  03
4     A     0.99     2000  04
5     A     0.55     2000  05
```

To a dataframe which looks something like this

```
code  name  returns  date
1     A     0.66     07-01-2000
2     A     0.32     14-01-2000
3     A     0.66     21-01-2000
4     A     0.99     NA
5     A     0.55     05-02-2000
```

This was done by following command

```
setDT(weekly)[,date:=as.Date(paste(year, week, 5, sep="-"), "%Y-%U-%u")]
```

But, I dont know why last week i.e., 52nd week... last date is missing.

I want to **replace NA with preceding date + 7 days.**

Output should look something like this

```
code  name  returns  date
1     A     0.66     07-01-2000
2     A     0.32     14-01-2000
3     A     0.66     21-01-2000
4     A     0.99     28-01-2000
5     A     0.55     05-02-2000


**Note- Here, year 2000 is just an example. Actually, NA occurs whenever month changes from Thursday.**
```

Comment: What about something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55692239/how-to-convert-from-yearweek-to-yearmonthday

Comment: Works fine for me, returns `2000-01-28` as expected.

Comment: Could there ever be an `NA` date gap of _more_ than one row?

Comment: Yes, it returns 2000-01-28. I am just giving an example here. In, year 2008, 52nd week last date is missing. Every time whenever month ends on Thursday, last date is missing.

Comment: I will add precise date.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah... 2010-01-01 is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always add 7 days to the last date, you can try something like that:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(new = as.Date.numeric(ifelse(is.na(date) == TRUE, lag(date) + days(7), date), 
                               origin =  "1970-01-01" ))
```

Output:

```
  code name returns       date        new
1    1    A    0.66 2020-01-07 2020-01-07
2    2    A    0.32 2020-01-14 2020-01-14
3    3    A    0.66 2020-01-21 2020-01-21
4    4    A    0.99       <NA> 2020-01-28
5    5    A    0.55 2020-02-05 2020-02-05
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "code  name  returns  date
1     A     0.66     07-01-2000
           2     A     0.32     14-01-2000
           3     A     0.66     21-01-2000
           4     A     0.99     NA
           5     A     0.55     05-02-2000
           ", header = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date.character(date, tryFormats = c("%d-%m-%y")))
```